# Getting a second input from same text box

Tags: c#, random, do-while

I am in a C# class and our assignment is to create a random number generator and have the user guess the number.  Once the user makes a guess the program tells the user if it is too high or low, then allows them to modify their guess. It also keeps track of the number of guesses a user has completed.

My issue is that after the first run through it will not allow the user to enter a new guess.  It either keeps the first entry or if I clear the entry says it is invalid input.  Any and all help is appreciated.  Because this is a homework assignment I am required to user certain elements, such as try catch, and a repeating loop such as a for loop, or a do while loop.  Thanks for your help.

```
private void Guess_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int Answer = random.Next(0, 99);
        int User_Guess = 0;
        int Guess_num = 0;

        do
        {
            User_Guess = int.Parse(Guess_txtbx.Text);
            Guess_num++;
            if (User_Guess < Answer)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your answer is too low, try again.");
                Guess_txtbx.Clear();
                Guess_txtbx.Focus();
                User_Guess = int.Parse(Guess_txtbx.Text);
            }
            else if (User_Guess > Answer)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your answer is too high, try again.");
                Guess_txtbx.Clear();
                Guess_txtbx.Focus();
                User_Guess = int.Parse(Guess_txtbx.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your answer is correct! It took you " + Guess_num + "number of guesses.");
            }
        } while (User_Guess != Answer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Display error message
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You clear the Guess_txtbx field and then parse the empty value afterwards. This will probably throw an exception. Since the value is already parsed (the first statement in the loop), the following parsing in the conditional blocks is redundant.

Comment: I'm not sure the loop makes sense. They give one answer, the click event fires when they click Guess, you figure out whether high or low, then display message and wait for their next answer and button click. Which would mean the answer should be determined outside of click event.

Answer (score 0):

You use the 'do-while' loop inside the click event handler, it leads to blocking the UI thread and hanging of the entire application.

You can use something like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Answer = random.Next(0, 99);
        User_Guess = 0;
        Guess_num = 0;
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    int Answer;
    int User_Guess;
    int Guess_num;

    private void Guess_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            User_Guess = int.Parse(Guess_txtbx.Text);
            Guess_num++;

            if (User_Guess == Answer)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your answer is correct! It took you " + Guess_num + "number of guesses.");
                Guess_num = 0;
                return;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your answer is too {0}, try again.", User_Guess > Answer ? "High" : "Low"));
            Guess_txtbx.Clear();
            Guess_txtbx.Focus();
         }

        catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
    }
}
```

}

I've checked my code. It running and executing always. You had the one more mistake in your code: you wrote in the click event handler that random number generates with the ever users click on the button then you always had the different numbers and a user couldn't guess the right number at all.

Comment: Fabjan:  through some research I have found that you are absolutly corrcect that my GUI is locked, and will not allow a new entry within the button click.  I guess I'm not sure where to put it then, and when I inserted your code, it doesn't allow me to read any input.